# Verificar se uma chave existe em um dicionário

Tags: python, python-3.x

Como posso fazer para verificar se uma chave existe dentro de um dicionário em Python?

Comment: O que seria uma variável dentro de um dicionário? Seria uma determinada chave do dicionário?

Comment: Isso, por exemplo:`a = {"a" : "apple"}` 
Como faço para verificar se a é uma chave do dicionário

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Para verificar se determinada chave existe em um dicionário no Python, basta fazer:

```
if "chave" in dicionario:
    print("O dicionário possui a chave")
```

Ou seja, se considerarmos o dicionário:

```
d = {'a': "Valor de A", 'b': "Valor de B"}
```

Podemos fazer:

```
if 'a' in d:
    print("Dicionário possui a chave 'a'")

if 'b' in d:
    print("Dicionário possui a chave 'b'")

if 'c' in d:
    print("Dicionário possui a chave 'c'")
```

> Veja funcionando no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/mTfTdD)

A saída gerada é:

```
Dicionário possui a chave 'a'
Dicionário possui a chave 'b'
```

Comment: Muito obrigado amigo!